# It's posible to map shift + shift on vi?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to configure a key-mapping using shift+shift, is this posible ?

I have tried:

```
<S-S> But this maps shift + S
<S><S> and this that maps to unknown
```

Comment: No. Ill let Ingo Karkat do his standard blurb...

Comment: @FDinoff: ... and here it comes :-) This question is only partially related, though. The reason for my standard reply is to get vim_dev moving to allow such combinations in Vim 8, as I need more mappings... maybe the amount of confusion here on SO convinces them to tackle this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot map to *modifier keys* (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>) alone; they can only be used **in combination with other keys** that represent printable characters (like `<C-a>` = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>). That's mostly due to the fact that terminals do not send keypress events for modifier keys alone. There are unfortunately even limitations in those combinations (also in GVIM). Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished.